# Are alternatives to spacesuits, like one person pods, being developed?

Tags: astronauts, spacesuits

I'm thinking that for extended zero gee extravehicular activities (say space construction) a single person pod (if that's the right word) would be more all round useful than a space suit. Faceplate and arms for visibility and hands-on activities but no legs, enough room to draw head and arms back inside to allow the user to scratch, wipe away sweat, eat, piss etc, foot operated motion and other controls leaving hands free, gyro stabilisers and extendable clamps for working stability and leverage. Some of the pod's systems might be internally accessible in emergencies. I think they would be more comfortable and allow longer work times without reducing manual dexterity and could be made compact enough for most purposes.

Comment: To urinate in zero gravity requires some precautions to avoid drops floating in the pod. The problem is not solved by only enough room.

Comment: Organic Marble - small work vehicles versus alternative to spacesuit - the duplication might be in my choice to call it a pod. Legless, roomy spacesuits? I'll have a think about whether to edit.

Comment: Uwe - true, but surely it's easier to use your preferred collection method if you can use hands. More comfortable than being connected to plumbing for extended periods I'm thinking.

Comment: Should I delete the question given that old hands here believe that it's a duplicate? I can see that the line between mobile spacesuit and single person work vehicles isn't clear and that previous question can encompass what I have in mind.

Comment: @KenFabian The important thing is this: does the indicated duplicate answer your question or is it phrased in a way such that a proper answer to it would answer your question? If so, then there is no reason to reopen this question. (Deletion is up to you--I wouldn't recommend it since duplicates can help people find questions.) If not, then edit this question to clarify what you are looking for that is different than the other question, and we can consider reopening it.